# Question about comaximal ideal proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $A$ be a ring and $M\subseteq A$ a maximal ideal. Show that if $I\subseteq A$ such that $I\not\subseteq M$, then $M$ and $I$ are comaximal($M+I=A$).

I cannot find the proof for this statement.

Comment: I have edited your question. Please, refrain from using multiple exclamation marks in your question in the future.

Comment: hint: let $x$ be an element of $I$ that is not in $M$ and and consider the smallest ideal that contains both M and $x$.  Then note that $M+I$ must contain that ideal.

Answer (score 2):

$M+I$ is by definition an ideal, it contains $M$, and since $I \not\subseteq M$, it strictly contains $M$. Since $M$ is maximal, it follows that $I+M=A$.